# Last 3 rows of ListView are hidden behind Soft Keyboard. I want them to scroll up and view. How to do that?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView and EditText above it. Clicking on EditText opens SoftKeyboard. I scrolls up ListView, but last 3 items of ListView remain hidden behind Soft Keyboard. I want to scroll these last 3 items as well.

Comment: hii, got any solution for this

Comment: Not yet. But alternative is: Just hide soft keyboard when you scroll the List.

Comment: yes i do same thing.

Answer (score 0):

in you activity tag in manifest use this

```
<activity
...
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

or

```
<activity
...
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
 </activity>
```

Edit 1:

try to add in oncreate

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

or with adjust resize also

Edit 2:

add this line in your main layout of the xml file

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: Check your theme usage. They may override the windowSoftInputMode.

Comment: i have edited my answer try to add in oncreate..some times manifest dont work

Comment: @mach: U r right. It is related to Theme.I tried separate app with ListView and without theme, that's worked. But, I am not able to find anything in my theme which is overriding it.

Comment: @mach: I removed Theme from <application> tag in Manifest.xml as well. But no success.

Comment: You are not inheriting a fragment or activity that sets the theme in the onCreate()?

Comment: @mach: Hi, there is nothing like that. You can download Nimbuzz Messenger application and on "Contacts" screen, u can check the behaviour.

Comment: Hi you found solutions

Answer (score 0):

i have some problem, 
i got a solution that hide keyboard when we click on other then edittext

so i use below method, that i found on stackoverflow

try this

```
public void setupUI(final View view, final Activity activity) {

        // Set up touch listener for non-text box views to hide keyboard.
        if (!(view instanceof EditText)) {

            view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    try {
        if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity
                    .getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            activity.getCurrentFocus().clearFocus();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

                    return false;
                }

            });
        }

        // If a layout container, iterate over children and seed recursion.
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {

            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {

                View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);

                setupUI(innerView, activity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i hope it works for you

Comment: It will do the alternative. It will hide the soft keyboard, which is default behaviour in many apps. It's ok to do that.

Comment: But, is there any way to scroll all the rows up?

Comment: i facing same problem, i try many things but not success so i decide to hide keyboard when user touch my keyboard.